# How to implement a table layout inside a list view

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout

I want to implement a layout which resembles Bank's PassBook. So I thought should I implement table layout inside a list view.

Here is a sample passbook example.

### DATE        PARTICULARS    DEBIT     CREDIT    BALANCE

### 12/06/2014  Withdraw       200                  10000

### 11/06/2014  Deposit                  200        10200

Comment: you can use `LinearLayout` with `weight` instead of `TableLayout`, according to your requirement. It will work.

Comment: can you give a sample code snippet?

Comment: I have added Ans. Ckeck it.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. should I fix the width of textview as in some rows if the value of text is more then it will not be common for every row.

Comment: If you want that all Columns have same width then don't fix the width, otherwise you can, and don't forget to accept the ans if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create xml layout like below

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/action_type"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

use this layout as list item for your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayAdapter for your ListView.

In there, you can inflate the Layout for the items of the list, be it a TableLayout, or something other.

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SomeObject> {

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SomeObject> someObjectList) {

        super(context, resource, someObjectList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view;

        //view recycling
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the single row with whatever layout you like
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_row, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }


        SomeObject item = getItem(position);

        //fill the view with data
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setText(item.getDate());
        ...

        return view;
     }
     ...
}
```

Here's a little to read about ListViews and ArrayAdapter:
https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView[1](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)